# split columns in to two while recoding in r

Tags: r, split

I have following data:

```
set.seed(123)
M1 <- c(sample(c("AA", "AB", "BB"), 5, replace = T))
M2k <- c(sample (c("AG", "GG", "AA"), 5, replace = T))
M3l <- c(sample (c("AT", "TT", "AA"), 5, replace = T))
M4  <- c(sample (c("CT", "TT", "CC"), 5, replace = T))

  #in real data M1 .......M1000 

myd <- data.frame (M1, M2k, M3l, M4)
```

I want split each M into two M1a, M1b for M1, M2ka, M2kb for M2k and so on. Similarly content of cell will be split AB  will be A in M1a column and another M1b column. Also I want to re-code A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, G = 4, T = 5, else = NA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** `reshape::colsplit` will split by `''`

Using `reshape::colsplit`.

```
library(reshape)

split_col <- function(.col, data){
 .x <- colsplit( data[[.col]], names =  paste0(.col, letters[1:2])) 

}

# split each column and combine
new_data <- do.call(cbind,lapply(names(myd), split_col, data = myd))
# convert each new column to a factor  with levels 1:5 as requested.
new_data_2 <- do.call(data.frame, 
  lapply(new_data, factor, levels = c('A','B','C','G','T'), labels= 1:5))

  M1a M1b M2ka M2kb M3la M3lb M4a M4b
1   1   1    1    4    1    1   3   3
2   2   2    4    4    5    5   3   5
3   1   2    1    1    1    1   3   5
4   2   2    4    4    5    5   3   5
5   2   2    4    4    1    5   3   3
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works with this small example, when I tried in bigger example it doesnot - show option shows that it split and name variables to some point such as variable and then stops ! the error is "'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]"

Comment: I discovered the cause of problem was <NA> in the dataset. I need to optimize this so that NA or <NA>

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution, with no particular advantage except that I find it easy follow:

```
myd$M5 = c("AB", "GT", "GA", "QW", "CK") # Add another test column.

mat = as.matrix(myd) # Convert to matrix for speed and indexing benefits.

# Construct new column names.
new_names = character(length=ncol(mat) * 2)
new_names[seq(1, ncol(mat) * 2, 2)] = paste(colnames(mat), "a", sep="")
new_names[seq(2, ncol(mat) * 2, 2)] = paste(colnames(mat), "b", sep="")

# Create empty matrix with correct column names.
newmat = matrix(ncol=ncol(mat) * 2, nrow=nrow(mat))
colnames(newmat) = new_names

# Split columns.
for (i in seq(1, ncol(mat))) {
    newmat[, (i * 2) - 1] = substr(mat[, i], 1, 1)
    newmat[,  i * 2     ] = substr(mat[, i], 2, 2)
}

# Use named vector to recode data.
recode = c(A=1, B=2, C=3, G=4, T=5)
newmat[] = recode[newmat]

newmat
#      M1a M1b M2ka M2kb M3la M3lb M4a M4b M5a M5b
# [1,] "1" "1" "1"  "4"  "1"  "1"  "3" "3" "1" "2"
# [2,] "2" "2" "4"  "4"  "5"  "5"  "3" "5" "4" "5"
# [3,] "1" "2" "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "3" "5" "4" "1"
# [4,] "2" "2" "4"  "4"  "5"  "5"  "3" "5" NA  NA 
# [5,] "2" "2" "4"  "4"  "1"  "5"  "3" "3" "3" NA
```

Answer (score 0):

mnel already gave a pretty straight forward answer.  This is me playing with my package in process (qdap) that is on GitHub though not on CRAN yet:

**To Install qdap**

```
# install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("qdap", "trinker")
```

**Solving the problem:**

```
lapply(seq_along(myd),  function(i){
    myd <<- colsplit2df(myd, (i+i-1), paste0(names(myd)[i+i-1], 
        letters[1:2]), sep="")
})

data.frame(apply(myd, 2, function(x) as.numeric(text2color(x, 
    c("A", "B", "C", "G", "T"), c(1:5, NA)))))
```

The work horse of this code is `colsplit2df` (returns a data.frame) and `text2col` (designed to recode text for wordcloud coloring; really a dictionary lookup tool).  This really isn't what these functions are designed to do, just playing and seeing how they can be extended.

Answer (score 0):

Using qdap with  more stable solution:

```
x <- colsplit2df(myd, 1:ncol(myd), sep="")
colnames(x) <- paste(rep(colnames(myd), each = 2), letters[1:2], sep=".")

##   M1a M1b M2ka M2kb M3la M3lb M4a M4b
## 1   1   1    1    4    1    1   3   3
## 2   2   2    4    4    5    5   3   5
## 3   1   2    1    1    1    1   3   5
## 4   2   2    4    4    5    5   3   5
## 5   2   2    4    4    1    5   3   3
```